# Importing python libraries from outside directory

Tags: python, class, import

I am trying to import python files which have been developed. Initially, when all files were in the same directory then I there was no problems with them. However, I decided to split projects to dedicated directories. After that, I am unable to import files anymore.

My file structure is similar to the following:

```
dirFoo\
    mainFoo1.py
dirFoo\
    mainFoo2.py
dirFooCommon\
    commonFoo.py
    commonFoo2.py
```

Initially, I was trying to change the import path of my mainFoo1.py and do:
from `dirFooCommon import commonFoo`. However, that approach gave me the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'.

Apart from that, I tried to use `imp.load_source` which seems that is working. Unfortunately, this is generating so additional problems. For example what if some of the commonFoo.py libraries must include others? In this case, each of them needs to use an absolute project path, which will be a problem when I will try to use common libraries in any other place.

Do you have an idea what should I do to include my common libraries to my main projects?

Comment: Look into [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages).

Comment: Consider using \_\_init\_\_.py files to convert your Python files into modules and your directories into packages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/6014095

Comment: @Kronosfear I heard that in python > 3.3 you don't need doing __init__.py anymore. Also, I tried that and I have the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dirFooCommon'

Answer (score 0):

You can use this folder structure that will allow you to call each package and module properly.

```py
dirFoo\  <=== This is a package know 
    __init__.py 
    mainFoo1.py
dirFoo2\  <==== Change the name or you will have namespace issue
    __init__.py
    mainFoo2.py
dirFooCommon\ <=== This is a package know 
    __init__.py
    commonFoo.py
    commonFoo2.py
```

So in `mainFoo1.py`you can call `commonFoo.py`like this

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dirFooCommon")

from dirFooCommon import commonFoo
```

To replace `sys.path.append`you can also add the folder in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Using sys.path.append() do I need to provide an absolute or relative path to files?

Comment: An absolute path is prefered